# gerrit throwing an gerrit@localhost: Permission denied (publickey) error

Tags: encryption, ssh, rsa, gerrit

I have setup the Gerrit using docker-compose.

ref doc: https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/docker-gerrit

I am trying to login on the Gerrit server using SSH protocol.
http is working fine. but i need ssh as well for jenkins

ssh -vv -p 29418 localhost

logs:

```
[gerrit@957ec687d4a3 ~]$ ssh -vv -p 29418 localhost
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host localhost originally localhost
debug2: match not found
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host localhost originally localhost
debug2: match found
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 29418
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 29418.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version GerritCodeReview_3.3.3 (APACHE-SSHD-2.4.0)
debug1: no match: GerritCodeReview_3.3.3 (APACHE-SSHD-2.4.0)
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:29418 as 'gerrit'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: ecdh-sha2-nistp256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: ecdh-sha2-nistp256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:QJIkQCiy/Pi43QI2H6A9OBVOY4f+7tpIK+W+Nwi2C6g
debug1: Host '[localhost]:29418' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/gerrit/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:dBSjzg5IkLz0ShVN2T2ig8S+VuEB2/Qf4/l4t6YPv+Y
debug1: Will attempt key: /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:dBSjzg5IkLz0ShVN2T2ig8S+VuEB2/Qf4/l4t6YPv+Y
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /var/gerrit/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
gerrit@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I am trying these scenario inside the Gerrit container

please someone help on this isssue,

you can see in the below image add ssh key button is disable. I am not able
add the key.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would get enabled when you input a public ssh key in the box above where it says "New SSH Key"

Comment: Thanks you so much. I am chasing for this thing almost for a week.                                                        once again thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you are doing wrong

1. You should not login from within the gerrit container as it will use the gerrit user and ssh key. There is no gerrit user in gerrit in such a way
2. You should create a new user, are you using LDAP?
3. Next, log in to gerrit using that users credentials and add the public ssh key from the user in the user profile. Depending on your server url: https://myserver.net/settings/#SSHKeys
4. Now you should be able to connect

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I am using ldap to login on gerrit. But ssh keys option in gerrit setting is disable there. I am not able to add the keys there.

Comment: The SSH key is added to you user profile, not in the LDPA configuration, I have added the url to the answer

Comment: i have attached the image of my gerrit GUI. you can see in the image add ssh key button is disable.